# Microsoft Word 2016: math equation shortcut, hitting space bar changes nothing

Tags: microsoft-word, shortcuts, equations

I have an issue when writing shortcuts for equations in Word 2016. Say I want to write x². When I add a new equation and write x^2, then if I hit the space bar nothing happens. It doesn't automatically change it to a professional style, to x². 
Help?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "writing shortcuts for equations"? How are you adding the new equation? Typing equations using shortcuts works perfectly for me in Word 2016, I hold down the `Alt` key and press `=` in the middle of a sentence, that way your equations will be inset with your sentence. Or if you wish, you can just create an equation on a separate like with the same shortcut and type your `x^2` command as you have tried.

Mention what shortcuts you used and the approach you tried, and it's easier to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're talking about `x^2` turning into x<sup>2</sup> in the Equation environment (for which the shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>, as mentioned by prrao). In order for automatic conversion to Professional format to be activated, this setting should be selected:

- Design tab (under Equation tools while in an Equation environment)
- => Tools section (where the Professional, Linear, etc. buttons are)
- => the more settings button in the bottom right of that section ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkOeE.png))
- => "Automatically convert expressions to professional format"

Answer (score 3):

Under "Equation", in the "Conversions" section, switch to Unicode Input.

[You have to have to change conversion to Unicode Input instead of LaTex Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJNqH.png)

Comment: That did it for me, thank you!!
"Automatically convert expressions to professional format" was on but it would convert on demand only, switching to Unicode input made it convert automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Under "equation" mode on left you will see Unicode, Latex, Text and Convert. Click the down arrow little under "Convert" pick $$e^x$$ All-Profesional.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Word for Mac (Version 16.64). In

> Settings - AutoCorrect

i had to tick

> Automatically correct spelling and formatting as you type

and in "Maths AutoCorrect" I had to tick

> Replace text as you type